# Does jQuery.load() load after <script> content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Two questions:

1. Does `jQuery.load()` run after the content of `<script>` is completely downloaded?
2. If in case, there is a `<script>` in the document that will inject another `<script>` dynamically, does `load()` run after after the content of the 2nd script is downloaded or it will run after the original, non-dynamic content is loaded?

Thanks

---

The example for the 2) question is like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscrip1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).load( myscript2.functionA );
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Where myscript.js will inject myscript2.js into the dom. 
in which myscript2.js include the function myscript2.functionA

Obviously, I want to run myscript2.functionA after myscript2.js is loaded completely.

:)

Comment: Please provide an example to help explain what you're talking about.

Comment: How are you calling the .load() ? From my experience, it will run as and where it is called. So if .load() is called before your dynamic script is loaded, it will run before the dynamic script, however, if it is called after the dynamic script is loaded, it should run after it.

Answer (score 3):

The document ready event is fired when all of the resources referenced in the initial HTML have been downloaded (or timed out in case there are errors). If you dynamically inject a reference to another script (like the facebook api, google analytics, etc) it's readiness is undefined with relation to the document ready event.

If you want to check that your external script is ready you can check that an object that it creates has [been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var startAfterJqueryLoaded = function(){
    if(typeof jQuery === "undefined" ) {
        setTimeout( startAfterJqueryLoaded, 100 );
        return;
    }

    // jQuery is ready, do something
  }

  startAfterJqueryLoaded();

</script>
```

Or if you have control of the script you are dynamically injecting you can establish a global function that it will call when it's ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dynamicScriptIsReady = function(){
    // do something
  }
</script> 


// Dynamic.js
// ...Setup whatever

window.dynamicScriptIsReady();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `load` event handler within the standard `document ready` event handler wrapper, it will ensure that the external script is loaded first. You should consider this standard practice. The solution is simple:

```
<script src="myscrip1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).load( myscript2.functionA );
});
</script>
```

Comment: that doesn't work.  Because the myscript2.js will run after $(document).ready... $documetn(load) ... .  Therefore, myscript2.functionA will be undefined.  

The reason is that $document.ready will execute after myscript1 is ready & load, which is the code in the original HTML doc.  Dynamic script code will not be part of the HTML doc that ready & load will take care of.