# Analytics and Google Client ID get set

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am saving a Analytics client ID in a hidden field in my website by the following script:

```
// Assuming you are using jQuery
$(document).ready( function() {
  // Makes use of the Universal Analytics API 'ga' object
  ga(function(tracker) {
   var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
   $("clientId").val(clientId);
 });
 });
```

And then send it to my server.

But sometimes a user submits the form and there is no analytics client id saved in my database.

So my question is: When does a Analytics Client ID get set?

Only If a user is logged in with Google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client ID is set/generated whenever you send a hit to the GA servers. So, If you try to read the clientId after you have sent a pageview hit, you should always get a client ID.

Hope this answers your question.

You could also try something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(function() {
  $(document).ready(
    // Set the field value.
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a test and watched 10 of my filled in forms. 8 of them have a client ID and 2 not. So in my opinion my scripts are doing there job but maybe some users block the analytics?

Comment: It really depends on when the document.ready event is fired. If the event is fired before the pageview beacons are sent, you will not see a client id but will see the client id otherwise. See my edit for a possible solution.

Comment: What do you mean with sending the pageview call? Do you mean sending it to Google or sending it in the value in hidden field to my database?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I meant the former. I edited the answer above to show what I meant. Also, If you want a more specific solution, can you link to a page that is not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. My problem is that sometimes with for example this page: http://www.glasbestellen.nl/contact the client id get set and sometimes not get set. Maybe you can see the problem? I implemented universal analytics and in the footer you see the client id get set.

Comment: That is strange. When I load the page you linked to, I see that there is a javascript error on line 54: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'. As a result of this error, the tracking code at the bottom of the page is not being executed. Can you put the tracking code immediately after 
  ga('send', 'pageview'); and see if the id is set properly.

Comment: Oke, I'll gonna try that

Answer (score 0):

How frequently is this clientId not getting set?  There are a couple possibilities for why it might not be set.

(1) Some users block Google Analytics.  Google even provides [this tool](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) which allows them to do that.

(2) If your Javascript is running before the analytics.js library has loaded, then the tracker object may not exist yet.

My understanding is that $(document).ready does NOT guarantee that the analytics.js has loaded and created the tracker instance.  That's because the tracking code script reference is dynamically injected into the page to ensure that it loads AFTER all the resources referenced in the original HTML.  The issue of when Google Analytics scripts are loaded with respect to the document ready event [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247207/does-jquery-load-load-after-script-content-is-loaded).

Your site visitors definitely do NOT need to be logged in to Google in order to be assigned a clientId.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer! First, I am glad that I now know for sure that a user not have to be logged in with a Google account. I did a test with my filled in form results and watched 10 of them. 8 filled in forms have a Analytics client ID and 2 not. So in my opinion the scripts are doing there job, and some users use the blocker? Or it may still have to do with the document ready event?