# When linking to JQuery script is it OK to use the one on the JQuery website?

Tags: jquery

Hey there I've just been looking at using JQuery on my website I am developing.. A quick question; Am I able to just link to their script file? e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or do I need to upload my own copy to a server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the Google CDN (google it) and yes, you can use it.

Comment: yeah.. sure.. it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is considered good practice to use jQuery hosted on Google's CDN.

It is most likely already cached, it allows an additional parallel download (if the user agent is limited to only a few requests per domain) and it is probably served faster.

You can also [provide a fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo/4825258#4825258).