# Using Html5boilerplate's code to load JQuery very slow when run locally

Tags: jquery, html5boilerplate

I have been using the following code for loading JQuery in all of my projects.  I grabbed it from http://html5boilerplate.com/.  There is extensive disussion of this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

This code works great and seems pretty darn quick once I've put it up on the interwebs, but when I open my `.html` file locally it takes ~10 seconds per refresh.  Generally I get fed up and alter the code as follows:

```
<!-- uncomment when going live 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>-->

<!-- remove following line when going live -->
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I feel like I should not be getting the super-slow loading times, but it does resolve itself when comment out those lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're not serving the HTML through a web server.

The `//` prefix on the url indicates that it should use the same protocol as the current resource (usually either http or https)

Since you're not serving through http and instead through a file, it's trying to look for it on your local file system, eventually timing out.

The network tab on Chrome inspector shows it trying to load the following for me:

> file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
>   file:///C:/Users/[My Username]/Documents/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

It'll try to load those times and the file system (or maybe the browser) will eventually timeout.

The proper way is to serve it through a web server, either IIS if you're on Windows or Apache if you're on Linux/Mac (Apache also works in Windows, but IIS has better UI tools)

Comment: I suppose running it through XAMPP is the solution I'm looking for, I'd try it out now, but the darn thing broke somehow ;-) gotta give it a reinstall when I get a chance.

Comment: @ZachL. if you serve the file through a web server instead of just opening the file, it should work.

Comment: For the record, I'm kinda bummed with this solution though.  For small html/js/css projects I like to work right off the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Attempts to find jQuery in your file system, which means it will take a while to fail.  While looking at the Network tab of the developer panel in Google Chrome, it attempts to look for the file in `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`.Then, once it has failed to find the file, it loads jQuery (and successfully finds the file) using the next line:

`<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');`

To remedy the problem, add `https:` to the `src` of your script tag, like so:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That looks like it will work, but this will defeat the point of the protocol agnostic approach?