# In JavaScript how to wait for dynamically injected scripts are loaded before start using them?

Tags: javascript

**Without using any external library** how can I wait for a script to load before using it.

In my case I'm loading the scripts using:

```
(function (w,d,t,s,e,r) {

    e = d.createElement(o);
    r = d.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    e.async = 1;
    e.src = g;
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)

})(window, document, 'script', '//mydomain.com/path/to/script.js');
```

And later:

```
// then later I want to use some code form the script:
var obj = new classFromTheInjectedScript();
```

Is there away to wait for the script to load and then start using it?

> **Note:** I have a way that I can trigger an event within the script I want 
>   to load and then listen to it as you can see below, but is this a good idea?

```
(function(w,d){

    document.addEventListener('scriptLoadedCustomEvent',onScriptReady);

    function onScriptReady(){
        // what I need to do goes here!
    }


})(window,document);
```

Comment: Using a custom event like that is a fine idea.

Comment: Assuming "without using any external library" includes jQuery, it's worth considering that your homebrew event, while effective, will require you to handle the case wherein the script can't be loaded. I think what you're looking for is a 'promise'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `onload` and `onerror` events for `<script>` tag. Good example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement).

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do something like this!

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url; //source 

    var callback = function (){ 
      // do stuff after loaded
    }
    script.onload = callback;

    document.head.appendChild(script); //inject where you need it to be
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would be help to load a script and on successful load.. you can wait and perform your actions

```js
function loadScript(url) {
  const w = window;
  const d = document;
  const l = () => {
    const s = d.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = url;
    const x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);

    s.addEventListener('load', () => {
      // This loads the script
      yourFunctionAfterScriptLoaded();
    });
  };
  if (w.attachEvent) {
    w.attachEvent('onload', l);
  } else {
    w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
  }
}
```

or you can directly use the script onload function as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058442/4527878)

Answer (score -2):

you could read the file source and inserting it in a script tag manually, so you will have the AJAX response event