# Can a Google Chrome extension detect when all scripts finish loading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to develop a Chrome extension that scrapes data off the page, but this can happen only after all of the pages ajax finish loading their remote content.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `"run_at": "document_end"`?

Comment: Does this fire more than once? The script can run after the document finishes loading.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't detect when all scripts are finished loading.  It is fairly common for a page to wait a couple seconds after the 'onload' event to request an additional round of scripts -- for example, if you want to delay-load ads but don't want to slow down the initial page rendering.

However, extensions do have a flag to run at "document_idle".  This flag supposedly makes Chrome wait until the page is "idle" before injected the extension's script.  It would not, however wait for a delay-loaded script and it may not even wait for a slow XHR.

More information can be found at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do that, but if you want to check if a particular external script is loaded you can check this:
[Verify External Script Is Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521298/verify-external-script-is-loaded)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31358282)