# javascript: check whether expression is evaluatable or not?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have Random Expression which is given By users (*Eg: 2+3*5,21*+(4)7,*-54+3*). These Expression can contain any number of operand or operator to form a expression.I need to evaluate These Expression to get the Answer.I tried to evaluate using **eval()** function but Problem is when  a wrong Expression is passed to **eval()** functions it throws a error and program halt.I tried it by

```
if(eval(exp))
{    
    //Action Expression is evaluatable
}
else
{
    //expression is not Evaluatable
}
```

but did not worked and produced error message

```
"SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal."
```

Due to variety in expressions' nature it would be difficult for me  to construct  check statements before evaluating.
can you please suggest how can i simply check whether the expression passed to eval() function is  correct or not ?

Comment: Try-catch the error? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Use `try`/`catch`, which is for dealing with thrown errors. `if`/`else` is for checking boolean conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch the error:

```
try {
        eval(exp); 
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put the content of your script in the "script" tag on the fly, and then check the return of the error function. Or define a variable at the end of your script and checks if it exists after the execution.

Or mayber you can find a response here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522483/2007701 !!

Comment: Why would OP need this instead of a simple `try-catch`?