# How to track .js files loaded when website page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, routes, localhost, open-source

I am trying to contribute to the Hospital Frontend, I am unfamiliar with the file structure however and want to be able to find which files are loaded when I load the page from my local server. Is there a tool that can allow me to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: If i correctly understand the question, than you can just open the "Network" tab in Dev Tools of any browser and look for the loaded files. See here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521298/verify-external-script-is-loaded
looks like what you are looking for is described in that SO post very well.