# Webpack: How to load the module on page load?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, autodesk-forge, es6-modules

Using webpack, I'm creating a Library extension. The issue is that the Library **should be loaded** from a [certain server.]

The main class of the extension stats with:

```
class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  // ...
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/extension.js"></script>
```

The issue is that the `Autodesk` constant isn't a npm module, so when both JS files are included this error is thrown:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Autodesk is not defined
```

My question is: How to build this extension in a way it will be evaluated after page load?

**Obs:** It works when using the webpack dev build but won't work with the production build.

**Edit:** It works the I load the JS files on the main page. This issue happens when the libs are loaded in an AJAX request (Specifically I'm using it in a [Bootstrap tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs))

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "WEBPACK_ENV=build webpack",
    "dev": "WEBPACK_ENV=dev webpack --progress --watch --log-level=debug"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error. What you're describing should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qLzvsyk5/2/

Comment: Which version of webpack do you use ? If you made it work for the production build would you ask this question ? (I might have an idea why the prod won't work)

Comment: @ChrisR updated my question with the package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewer lib is quite big, you have to have to wait for that `viewer3d..min.js` has been loaded into your web page. Otherwise, the `Autodesk` object won't be created in the `window` object of your web page.

I think it hasn't been completely loaded for a page in AJAX calls, you can verify if the `Autodesk` object is an attribute of the `window` like this way for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9521360/7745569) in the tab content page:

```
if( typeof window.Autodesk === 'undefined' ) {
    $.getScript( '<external JS>' );
}
```

Since I only see the `package.json` here, I have no idea how you implement your app and make the assumption above. If it's incorrect, please consider sharing more details without the confidential parts, or send a none-confidential reproducible case to `forge.help [at] autodesk.com`

Comment: Thanks @Eason. Yes, I used the `typeof` with a `setTimeout` loop to wait for the Autodesk constant and it worked. Anyway, would be grand if you could publish the  code as a module, would make our life easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpack.config.js`, configure the [UglifyJsPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#uglifyoptions) like this:

```
plugins: [
  new UglifyJsPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
      mangle: {
        keep_classnames: true
      }
    }
  })
]
```

This will tell the UglifyJsPlugin in Webpack to avoid changing the classnames, so you'll be able to reference to `Autodesk`.