# How to check HTTP Status Code of dynamically added *.js

Tags: javascript

for a project I need to check the Response Code of a dynamically added JS into DOM. So Code looks basically like this one:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "http://www.example.com/dynamic-XXX.js";
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

The XXX will change and I am loading the File from Google Cloud Storage. So if I have a 200, everything is fine. But I need to check if I have 201 Status Code.

Any Ideas how to solve this in a nice way ?

Comment: You should be able to set an onload and an onerror attribute (or add the equivalent with addEventHandler).  See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521298/verify-external-script-is-loaded I think it can helps you.