# How to check if script is already loaded and executed?

Tags: javascript

I have an abstract script, `any-script.js`. It is included it into the html, or it is loading if it is needed. I have some code which calls some some other code, which calls function from loaded script. How can I check this script to know if it loaded 100% and executed? I don't know what code will be called, it is just some abstract callback.
If I load this script dynamically, all goes fine, I can add an event lister and to wait until it fires `script.addEventLister("load")`. But if my script is already in DOM with async attribute, and if it is loaded, I can't just add some evet listener, because it will not fire. At other side I can't to be sure, that the script was loaded. Because `script tag in dom !== script is loaded`.

1. `script.addEventLister("load")` - is working only if you 100% know, that the script is not loaded
2. `script tag in dom !== script is loaded`

May be exists some browser api to correctly check this?

Comment: the load event listener is usually added on a scripts element built dynamically. Anyway if you want to quickly circumvent the fact that it may have been fired before you even added the event listener, try to add the onload attribute on your `<script>` tag so it will be defined for sure before it will be loaded

Comment: Another way to do it is check for functions or variables that exist only after that script has loaded. For example `if (window.functionFromScript) {console.log("loaded")}`

Comment: Usually you'd have the `any-script.js` itself include the logic for that, like Google Tag Manager and other services do it. One example is to have outer code initialize a global variable as array if not yet existing and then call `.push` with a callback. The `any-script.js` code would then check if the array exists and call all callbacks inside and then also replace it with an object `{ push: fn => fn() }` so that anybody calling `push` _after_ the script was loaded would immediately get the callback executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verify External Script Is Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521298/verify-external-script-is-loaded)

Comment: @DiegoD `onload` attribute can help, but this approach will split logic across different code parts and will make it difficult to maintain. It is very difficult to support and debug such things.

Comment: @Kokodoko it will work if you know that is exporting from script and you have full control. If script is bundled and not exporting anything, this will not work.

Comment: You mean you're loading a complete bundle from a separate project, without control over how it was bundled? How do you access the variables and functions that are inside that bundle?

Comment: Think about it as an API to provide safe way to execute custom code which depends on some script. `run("script.js", () => {cool_code..})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no official API to check this. But there are some approaches to achieve this.

- If script is loaded dinamicaly, you have to add an `load` event listener `script.addEventListener("load", event => ...)`
- If script is already in DOM, it must have an attribute `onload`, to track loading state and to write somhere globaly this info.
- If script is already in DOM, you can remove it from DOM and load it dimaicaly one more time (shit way), using first variant.

How to maintain this it is only your brain fu..

May be in the future we will have some more consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little snippet I'm using sometimes to check if a function is ready. So to know if your js is loaded you just test 1 of its function.
Not the cleanest but that can work...

```js
function fireWhenReady(function1, callback) {
    if (typeof function1 != 'undefined') {
        if (callback && typeof (callback) === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout(fireWhenReady, 100);
    }
}

//call
fireWhenReady(NAME OF YOU FUNCTION, function () {
   // function is ready
});
```

Comment: 1. I don't know nothing about global exports in script. It is an any abstract script you can imagine.
2. What will happen if I will make hundreds of calls and script will not load by some reason? Or it src attribut is not assigned yet?
Any way brute forcing is not acceptable.

Comment: I understand. Yes with complementary information in your comment, not a good idea to use this script. sorry

Answer (score 0):

If the script is not a `type="module"` script and you have control of the target script then you can do this:

```js
// index.js

async function script_has_loaded(src) {
  const script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)
  if (!script) {
    throw new Error('script doesnt exist')
  }
  if (script && script.loaded) {
    return
  }
  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    script.onload = res
    script.onerror = rej
  })
}
```

```js
// target.js
console.log('running script')
document.currentScript.loaded = true
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Example:

Your webpage would have this:

```
<script src="any-script.js" async></script>
document.addEventListener("custom_event", () => {
    //runs this code only after any-script.js has been loaded
});
```

And your any-script.js file would have this: (NOTE: Place that dispatch line at the bottom of your code.

```
const custom_event = new Event('custom_event');
document.dispatchEvent(custom_event);
```

So basically you have a webpage listening for a custom_event and you have a custom event fire off from your any-script.js file at the bottom of it. Giving you your desired result.

Comment: The <script> element already triggers a load event, it's unclear to me what the CustomEvent provides more here.

Comment: You're missing a key point here. Using the load event of the window object ensures that the script file specified in the <script> tag has been loaded and parsed by the browser. It doesn't guarantee that the JavaScript code within that script has finished executing, especially if the script contains asynchronous operations or if it's dynamically loading additional resources.

Comment: If you want your JS to run first you either have to use the suggestion I gave or use a callback function.

Comment: I'm talking about the script's load event which will fire once its content has been loaded and executed.

Comment: You're not listening. A script's load event doesnt fire AFTER its JS has been executed. It only fires AFTER it's been loaded. Try it yourself.

Comment: Yes it does execute the script first then fires the load event. The snippet in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78038595/3702797) proves that (otherwise clicking on the script button first would throw that `$` doesn't exist), and it's what [the specs ask](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#execute-the-script-element) (at the end of that algo)

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#blocking_rendering_till_a_script_is_fetched_and_executed

Comment: What do you think the render-blocking feature has to do in here? I mean, I linked to the actaul specs. What more do you want? There is no more authoritative than that. Even the (often good quality) MDN docs, do at the end link to these as the authoritative source.

Comment: You linked something that has nothing to do with the issue. OP asked "How can I check this script to know if it loaded 100% and executed?" LOADED AND EXECUTED. The onload event DOES NOT ensure both.

Comment: Try it yourself...
Move the external script (the javascript code on this page to your localhost) and see what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/wgsh3Lbj/

Comment: I linked to the specification of "executing a script", which does define how scripts are executed and when the load event is fired. That's precisely what this is about. The page you built in JSFiddle would throw an error because the script defining the function `handleLoad` will only be parsed after the external script is entirely executed, and after its `load` event is fired. Maybe you meant to set an `async` attribute on the external script? In that case [it would work just as expected.](https://planet-tested-date.glitch.me/)

Comment: You used a loop of 3000. Yes, it may execute SOME but not guaranteed to do all. The reason i did a loop with a larger number is to simulate tasks which could take awhile to complete. Use the example I actually typed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257048/discussion-between-kaiido-and-twalow).

Answer (score 0):

One lateral-thinking solution would be to either switch to [ES-modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), or to at least use the dynamic [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) operator to load your script instead of a `<script>` tag, even from classic scripts.

The browser will take care of loading said script only once. So this won't tell you if the script is already loaded, but it removes the initial problem and you don't need to care about it anymore.

```js
let value;
// Test import()
document.querySelector("button").onclick = async () => {
  await import("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js");
  console.log("script imported", !!$);
  if ($.FOOBAR !== value) {
    // Should not happen
    console.log("ERROR: We did run the script again!");
  }
  $.FOOBAR = value = Math.random();
}
// Test <script>
document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].onclick = async () => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js";
  document.body.append(script);
  await new Promise((res) => script.onload = () => res());
  console.log("<script> loaded", !!$);
  if ($.FOOBAR !== value) {
    // Will happen
    console.log("ERROR: We did run the script again!");
  }
  $.FOOBAR = value = Math.random();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  load script through <code>import()</code>
</button>
<button>
  load script through <code>&lt;script></code>
</button>
```

However beware, `import()` will only look at scripts imported as modules, i.e., from a `<script type="module">`, from `import` statements, or from `import()`, but it will reload once any script loaded from classic `<script>` elements.

Comment: Imagine situation, there are two scripts, one is yours, another not. You do not control how, when, where and by who they will be used. But you know the `url` of second script `https://cdn.blabla.com/unknown.js`.

You can check the presence of script with `src="https://cdn.blabla.com/unknown.js"` in DOM, but you don't have any information, is it loaded and executed or has 404 error.

Comment: Well if both scripts do load said resource as a module there would be no issue. Of course this works only if *both* do. If you have no control over that second script at all then there is always a risk of them loading the script in a way you didn't anticipate. But nowadays you should ask your library authors to provide an ESM version and be sure *they* do import all their resources through ESM.