# jQuery ui slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slideshow

So I created a simple slideshow with jquery and jquery ui. It works perfectly when I dragged the html into chrome, but when I uploaded the file to my server, the effect didn't work.
You can see the website on -guyzyl.org- (its the main page), or just the html file (which is the same as the one on the site -https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q3tnshbvmxu9ax/index.html-
any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wetFA/. Did you remember to upload jQuery on your server?

Comment: Ill make sure to do that next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing  all these js .. (Seen in firebug in console error)

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"
jquery...core.js
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"
jquery...lide.js
error: "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"
```

Also . i would suggest you to read from google CDN ( this jquery ui contains all the effect files)

```
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js
```

While keeping a local copy of it, so that in case it is not able to get it from google cdn , it can look in local path .(as in your case and doesn't brake your website)

Comment: np :) make sure you also download jquery.js from google only .  [correct way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014251/1085285)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the code itself: http://jsfiddle.net/ya8Yu/ is all of your code working.

you need to get your included files setup properly as Fidrizers suggested.

Also, in the future set up a jsfiddle so that we dont have to run around to gather all of your code and set up an environment to test.