# how to fallback twitter-bootstrap cdn to local copy

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

There are many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go) about how to fallback a JQuery CDN to a local copy by checking the existance of the global variable *JQuery*.

My question is , how to do the same to twitter-bootstrap ? Is there a variable defined in bootstrap so that I can check to make sure the CDN is available ?

BTW, I use *netdna.bootstrapcdn.com* as my bootstrap CDN

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I didn't see a specific variable that twitter-bootstrap exposes for this purpose and they don't attach all of their plugins to a namespace a la jQuery UI.  Your next best bet is to test for one of the bootstrap plugins.  Perhaps something like this:

```
if(typeof($.fn.modal) === 'undefined') {
    //load bootstrap locally
}
```

The unfortunate thing about this is that it is brittle.  If the modal plugin is ever renamed or removed this check would always fail.

Comment: Thanks Bhayden, I'll go this way. If the plugin is renamed, that will  definitely be a new version which should be aware of.

Comment: That's fine for the script but what about the CSS?

Comment: http://timjames.me/jquery-and-jquery-ui-fallbacks

Answer (score 40):

This is what I did and it works fine

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>    $.fn.modal || document.write('<script src="Script/bootstrap.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Comment: Nice reading from Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx