# Change color scheme using BootstrapCDN

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am building a website using Bootstrap and am getting the files through BootstrapCDN. What is the best way to go about modifying the color scheme when using BootstrapCDN. Am I better off to not use the CDN? For example - I want to change the color of the links. To do this I did `a{color:#000000}` - but want to know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Most simplest way. There's no harm in using bootstrap CDN.

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom-bootstrap-override.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[how to fallback twitter-bootstrap cdn to local copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575203/how-to-fallback-twitter-bootstrap-cdn-to-local-copy)

Comment: So this would just be overriding the css, right? Do you know of a way to more or less change all blue colors to a red color? Meaning - everywhere a blue color is used - use the red instead. That probably has to be done by using less?

Comment: @user1453561: Yes, There is it http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

You won't be able to use CDN then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use BootstrapCDN then you will need to override the css declarations that you want to change in another css file and host that file yourself.

If you have the inclination though you could edit the bootstrap .less files and then compile your own Bootstrap, or use http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html to create your own version to download - of course then you would either have to host them all yourself or use another CDN.