# scripts at the bottom in mvc 4 - Does not execute <scripts> in View page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

In `MVC4`, Views have `script` elements included at the bottom of the page.

Eg. In `_layout.cshtml` (under `Shared` folder), `<script>` tags are placed at the very bottom. While I understand that this makes the page load faster, the problem is actually this:

In my `Views`, sometimes I happen to use some scripts like `autocomplete`, something like below:

`<script type="text\javascript">
 ......
 </script>`

which is not functional because `scripts` tag are included at the very end of the page. **(JQuery is not even loaded at that time)**

Painfully, I had to move the `Script Bundle rendering` to the top of the page. Like,

```
render jquery first
then load scripts
```

so, am I missing something or I should always keep my `scripts` tag at the top of the `_layout.cshtml` page ?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Well, this answers my question finally.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585787/jquery-scripts-order-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. The key is:

put your scripts `anywhere` in your page but enclose them within a `@section Scripts`.

This will ensure that wherever you place your scripts, the `_layout.cshtml' renders them with the`JQuery` included.

Because, in your `_layout.cshtml` you have this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/RequiredBundles")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: +1 for providing the proper MVC solution to this issue, but could be improved by showing a "@section scripts" example.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put some scripts in $.ready which will only run when the whole page is loaded.

Comment: $.ready is fine. But, my question is, the jquery is not loaded when the document is ready because they are included at the bottom.

Comment: OK I see. You can simply move all scripts to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason the code generation does this is so if you add your own scripts into the bundles then they are executed after most of the html body is loaded into the dom.

If you make sure you use $.ready when coding your custom javascript then you should have no problem whether they are at the bottom of the page or in the head tag.

For personal preference I put them at the top (I like only having to look in the head tag to find which scripts are loaded) and make sure to use $.ready.