# Try loading CSS and JS online and if that fails load locally

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, load

I have a webpage to be hosted on a mobile device which is both Wi-Fi and 3G capable.

As 3G data may cost money and is generally limited, i want to minimize the amount of uploaded data by the device. So what I basically want to do is the following:

Try to load the jquery scripts online:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And **only** if  that fails to load correctly (e.g. if the user is not connected to the internet, just to the phone), load it from a local copy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-copy.js"></script>
```

The same applies for css files.

I've thought about having a `<script id="loadable"></script>` and then use `$("#loadable").load("url");` but obviously I depend on jquery to be loaded first, which is the file to be minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-copy.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: I'm gonna mark your question as answer, just because you were the 1st to provide a working solution, but i must say I don't like the begging comment.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer. I think bellow is the most elegant solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>')</script>
```

[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Answer (score 0):

check out how they do it in [HTML5 boilerplate.](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

If you take a look at the [bottom of the index.html file](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L27) within the GitHub repo, you'll see the following...

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-copy.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

**How does it work?**

- First, an attempt is made to grab the CDN version (Google's CDN url
  is used above, but of course you could link to any source you like).
- Immediately afterwards, we check for the jQuery global object.
- If jQuery does not exist, the obvious assumption is that we didn't
  manage to get the code from the CDN, so then we document.write a
  script tag to get a copy from a local source instead.

Comment: -1 if you're going to reference h5bp, _use_ the code that's in the file you're pointing at as a reference. h5bp's index doesn't include jquery **UI** from a cdn; it uses a protocol-relative url; and it doesn't needlessly encode and unescape the string to be written (the script tag). If the code were copy+paste usable, I wouldn't have commented, but it isn't.