# Is it possible to load jQuery UI from local if google cached version is unavailable?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have a page that uses jQuery UI. Ideally I would like to use the google cached version if possible, but if that was unavailable I would like to fall back on a local version.

Is this possible? I have been hunting through the html <script> tag reference but cant find anything to do a check and fallback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (while of course changing the URLs to suit your needs):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="/libs/jquery-ui.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was answered before:
[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

The same applies for jQueryUI ofcourse.

```
<script src="/path/to/external/jqueryui"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/local/jqueryui"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```