# jQuery CDN timeout fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fallback

I have read in several places how to fallback on a local copy of the jQuery library should the link hosted by either google or microsoft or other fail.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

My application works within an intranet environment however and occasionally the external jQuery link doesn't so much fail but takes a long time to load (due to external internet connection issues).

I'm wondering if there is a way to not only use such a fallback but set a timeout for the CDN link so that if the link takes a certain amount of time it should fail and call on the fallback.

Something like:

```
if(timetoloadjquery > n) {
    Use fallback local jQuery library.
}
```

Perhaps some kind of loop that checks if the jQuery is defined and if after so many iterations it is not....do something else?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Comment: (I never understood the CDN thing. Extra DNS lookups, extra downloads and still requires fallbacks.)

Comment: A `<script src>` is blocking, so the next `<script>` will **know** if the previous script loaded. No need for super super slow timeout.

Comment: What about `onerror=` and `onload=` in the `<script src>`?

Comment: @Rudie: Browsers download 3 or more (depending on browser) files simultaneously, how do they do that if each script source is blocking?

Comment: The execution is in order, after download. The next script block will only be executed after the previous has been downloaded & executed (or failed).

Comment: @DigitalD: The difference is that thread calls the fallback after the CDN link fails. In my case the CDN link can take a long time to timeout. I want to speed things up by failing the CDN script load after say 5 seconds because I don't want my page to wait for a long script download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. After 5-seconds have passed, Javascript checks if jQuery is available, if not, then loads the library from local server.

**1.** With a timer

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
  if(window.jQuery) return;
  var n = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  n.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("script"), n).src = "assets/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js";
}, 5000);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2.** This one doesn't have a timer, it loads a local version if the CDN version fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

Comment: @Barbs The issue with the first version (with timer) is that the slow loading library will continue to load. It won't abort it.

Comment: thanks I might just have to give up and host the library locally.

Comment: OK, let's assume jQuery is loaded twice. Will it somehow affect presentation or performance?
The biggest question is whether the page will show up BEFORE jQuery is loaded the second time.