# How can I confirm my external .js file downloaded in client system or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Google sites has been blocked in some of my client's office systems, so they can't able to view my site. How can I know whether file loaded or not? If not download I have to use .js file which stored in my server... Is it possible..

Comment: you could do something like `window.onload = function() { if (!jQuery) { .. load your local jQuery } }`

Comment: Why not insert Jquery libraries on your app path and calling it from it?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go

Comment: to reduce latency problem, I am using external CDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="myLocalPath/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: I got thanks :), sorry I disturbed with out taking effort by search

Answer (score 0):

Simple is that:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```