# Load scripts or css files from a CDN and still have local backup

Tags: javascript, css, cdn

I was wondering if I can have something like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and in case it is not available ...how can I load something like

```
<script src="../localjs/jquery.js"></script>
```

And same with CSS

I am asking because I work with CDN a lot, and sometimes I'm developing in Localhost and I am not able to connect to the internet and some scripts stop working, I was wondering if I can do this so I don't have to worry about changing them again and again between CDN and local files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Comment: Thank you, May be I didn't take the time to research more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following, right after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<body>
    <script>
    if (!jQuery) 
        document.write('<script src="/local/jquery.js"><\/script>');
    </script>

<!-- ... html ... -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../localjs/jquery.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Further reading: [CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

Comment: more elegant with "||" than "if" :)