# Javascript fallback when external js file failed to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fallback

I have a website with some java script functionality to get ip address from external js urls.

I would like to load external JavaScript files from either using URL-A or URL-B on fallback

ie, How to load script file from URL-B as fallback in case when URL-A is blocked/unavailable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)