# Calling bootstrap's css and js files from CDN or from root file

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, call, cdn

There are two ways to call bootstrap's css and js files.

1. From CDN
2. From root file

My question is what way is the best way to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is essentially "Should I use a CDN?".

The answer boils down to the following factors.

1. **You will need an internet connection all the time, even to test your code.**

   If you're on the move and don't have an internet connection, or one of your clients doesn't have one when you're demoing your code, then you're in trouble if you're using a CDN.
2. **The CDN will most probably be faster.**

   CDNs are designed for the sole purpose of serving files, fast. Most of the time, there are several mirrors serving the content, so files can be served fast to users around the world. Also, if you host it from your own domain, you might also include several cookies every time you serve the file, while the CDN will not.
3. **The CDN might go offline.**

   This is obvious, but it's a concern nonetheless. Check the reputation of the CDN you're planning to use.
4. **Your bandwidth usage will be minimised if you use the CDN.**

   If you host your site up somewhere, and your host has a limit on the amount of data it will transfer for you, commonly called 'bandwidth', then a CDN will help, since it won't count against your usage.

Keeping these factors in mind, the final choice is yours. However, for JS at least, I recommend using a CDN with a local fallback. An example done using jQuery can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014251/2141058.

Answer (score 0):

The CDN serves all the file for you, and will probably be faster than hosting them yourself. However, all you clients must have an internet connection. If your client will have an internet connection (if you are just writing a normal website), you should probably use the CDN.

If your client might not have an internet connect (if this site is internal to a company network) you should serve the files yourself, as your clients won't be able to reach the CDN via the internet.

Answer (score 0):

A foundation of a Content Delivery Network is that a different url/ip address then the primary domain of your website can receive client requests and response with resources.

This means the client's browser can and will make requests for resources that are from different urls/ips in parallel. So when you have a js file on your website, say www.mywebsite.com/site.js, the client's browser will request this resource and queue up the next resource, if the resource is from a CDN, aka a different url/ip, the client's browser can make a request to a different server in parallel. So if you are requesting, cdn.bootstap.com/boostrap3-min.js, this resource can be downloaded to the client without waiting for www.mywebsite.com/site.js to finish downloading to the clients browser.

So this means the overall website load time will be faster. but will it be human perceivable faster? If this is a website built for mobile devices then you may take advantage of a CDN because you need to optimize load times whenever you can. If the primary use of this website is a desktop website, with mild traffic, in a geographic region where broadband/decent connections is common place, it is not really worth having a CDN unless it is your own CDN server.

The bootstrap CDN server cannot be relied on, it is not part of your infrastructure. You should not trust that those that maintain the Bootstrap CDN will always have it up when people are going to your website. Sure, most likely, the CDN will be up and there is never an issue but if the Bootstrap CDN where to go down and your website doesn't look right or doesn't even work...You don't have the level of control you should have over the situation.

Also, using a CDN to a different domain and IE9 and IE10 and iFrames can cause issues, I wrote about this in my blog here:
http://www.sandiegosoftware.net/blog/script5-access-is-denied-error-in-internet-explorer-loading-jquery/

Use your own CDN server with a subdomain of the primary website domain or don't use a CDN is the best rule of thumb.