# Can you automatically choose between two <script src=""> files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So lets say you're implementing a website that uses jQuery HEAVILY. You could put some code like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and import it from some repository. If you're developing it without internet you could download the source and store it somewhere locally, then access it with some script like

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

But is there a simple way to have both? Such as if you can reach the repository use that, but if you can't use the local copy.

Comment: Why would you want to download it if you have it locally…? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: [A while ago I answered a related question on Programmers.StachExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/139380/7865).

Comment: It would be better if you just call your script locally as you can manage less http request.

Comment: @C-linkNepal, no, it's better to use a heavily cached reference especially when the user is highly likely to already have the script from other websites linking to a shared resource. In many cases it would lead to no HTTP request because the copy would be pulled from cache.

Comment: @C-link Nepal, first time you have to make a http request, even resource is in local repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Comment: @Pang Yeah looks like you're right. I tried finding a similar post, but couldn't earlier.

Comment: @Tilwin Joy I think you get extra benefits from calling it from Google's repository such as the latest updates, the code likely being cashed from other web searches, and optimized performance.

Comment: @skynab and BalusC yea, caching might be one benefit. When he said locally, i thought about something else because i'm a hybrid app developer. For the updates part, i think it might require code changes to benefit from it. for e.g. some code using a deprecated methods such as `live()` might break once updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for a variable in the first script. If it is not found, use document.write to create the second script tag. Here is an example for jQuery I found [here](http://snipplr.com/view/62495/google-cdn-jquery-loading-fallback/):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The fail-safe way of referencing scripts on a CDN is to link to the local copy only if the CDN has failed for any reason.

The way to do this is simply to check if anything within the script has executed. For jQuery this is simply checking whether jQuery exists:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.jQuery) document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-ver.sion.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Personally I have never had a script fail due to a CDN being offline, however I have had periods of internet outage. With scripts set up with a proper fallback, I've been able to continue local development as the pages still work without needing to connect to a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can add resources dynamically if required one is not available. for eg:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if( typeof $ != "function")
        {
            var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script= document.createElement('script');
            script.type= 'text/javascript';
            script.src= 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js';
            head.appendChild(script);
        }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though JQuery hosted on Google CDN should be safe enough, the codes below can be used as a fallback with requireJS.

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js',
            'js/jquery-ui.min.js'
        ]
    }
});

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```