# jQuery.noConflict() while loading jQuery asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

I am writing a Javascript library that requires jQuery 1.7 or higher. However, users of my library could be loading their own version of jQuery on their websites, which we can't control. Right now, I am loading jQuery asynchronously with a callback in my library, and using jQuery's noConflict(true) method to deal with version conflicts.

I have not come across any issues so far, but problems relating to asynchronous behavior and concurrency are random and very difficult to test. I am not very familiar with the details of asynchronous functions in Javascript, so I want an explanation. Let's say I have the following code:

Code on user's website:

```
// loading javascript library
<script type="text/javascript" src="library.js">

// loading jQuery version lower than 1.7.0
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js">
```

Code in library for loading jQuery asynchronously:

```
// set jQuery and $ to $j using noConflict()
loadScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
          $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
      });

function loadScript(url, callback){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

As I understand it, the user's page will first load my library's code, which will begin to load jQuery 1.11.1 asynchronously and use `jQuery.noConflict(true)` to rename the jQuery and $ global variables. The page will then continue to load jQuery 1.2.3 on the original page. So jQuery and $ should refer to 1.2.3, while $j will refer to 1.11.1.

However, is it possible for $j to ever point to 1.2.3 instead of 1.11.1 due to the asynchronous loading of jQuery or multithreading in browsers? For example, can the line that loads jQuery 1.2.3 be executed right before `$j = jQuery.noConflict(true)`, so that $j would now point to jQuery 1.2.3 (the current version of jQuery)? If so, what are some ways to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I think you are better to use `document.write` and make sure users are told to place your code in the head.

The reason I say that is `appendChild` would place your tag at end of any other scripts that might be in the head , which could be jQuery.

I would also suggest coming up with a more unique variable than `$j` which is not uncommon in noConflict situations.

Also, I would check if jQuery already exists and is a version that is compatible with your code before adding it again.
You can check version using `jQuery.fn.jquery`. If it already exists you could clone it to your noConflict variable.

Here's a post that has a lot of good reading :

**[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)**