# Facing issue in elevateZoom jquery liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, liferay, liferay-6

I use elevateZoom jquery for zooming image in liferay. I put my js file in css folder. and use following script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src='/css/jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
<script>
 jQuery("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({  

    zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
   }); 

</script>
```

But it gives me follwing warning and error
warning

```
07:19:51,317 WARN  [http-bio-8081-exec-76][code_jsp:128] {code="404", msg="/resources/demos/style.css", uri=/resources/demos/style.css}
```

error

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).elevateZoom is not a function
```

How can i resolved this error. Is there any other way for zooming image in liferay?
please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

404 error is for `style.css` not js so check if there is a file in that path

regarding js error init elevatezoom on document ready, make sure jquery is loaded. You may add a [fallback for loading jquery locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014251/4221558). Check other parts too there may be something else killing your page

```
$(function(){

  $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({  
    zoomType: "inner",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
  }); 

});
```

Comment: check other parts of your code somewhere your page is breaking, have you fixed link to style.css

Comment: i resolved error TypeError.. Buy i can't zoom image.its not working

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle