# Rails offline development with CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cdn, offline

I love to develop without the internet. But the problem is we cannot get image/css/javascript assets files by CDN.

I think the best way is

- On development env, try to get such asset files from CDN first, and

  - If possible, use it and cache it
  - If impossible, use cache

Alternative is

- Keep all such asset files in the repo too
- Use them on development env, use CDN on production env

But implementing these takes a bit time and I believe many developers face this problem.

So I want to know your way to solve this problem. If any good gem, it's fantastic.

My env is Rails4 without assets pipeline nor turbolinks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go