# How to load two different specific jquery files in Ipad and also dekstop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am trying write a code to load different scripts for different resolution
eg. for desktop it should be different scripts and also for mobile iPad etc different scripts

I am trying with this code but don't know where to start exactly

```
if ( $(window).width() > 800) { 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/examples.js"></script>

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
        sectionsColor: ['#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C'],
        css3: true
    });
}
else {
    // do Something ...
}
```

Comment: why do you need to do this? What if user simply has window resized?

Comment: i need to load two different scripts which making trouble  if i call same time so dividing it for mobile version  and desktop version

Comment: @charlietfl do you have any idea how to execute it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
if(...){
  document.write('<script  type="text/javascript" src="..."><\/script>');
}
else{
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="..."><\/script>');
}
```

See [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)