# How to detect if Moment js is loaded from CDN

Tags: javascript, momentjs, cdn, fallback

I want to create a fallback if moment js is not loaded from CDN. I couldn't find any helpful resource online, neither on [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com) to detect if Moment js is present.

Here's my code :

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // If moment.js is not loaded, use the fallback
    if () { 
        document.write('<script src="assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Moment attaches itself to the `window` when it loads, so you could do:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.moment) { 
        document.write('<script src="assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer writing the one-liner found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400432/5088712)

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script>window.moment || document.write('\x3Cscript src="assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>')</script>
```