# Understanding CDN's

Tags: jquery, cdn

I've been downloading jquery with:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

and for some reason, the link went bad.  Not a problem as I changed the link to use Microsoft's hosted CDN.  I'm wondering though if I should just download the files so to prevent this problem happening again in the future.  Is there any reason not to?

Comment: Link works fine. If you're accessing it locally then you'll need to include http: or https:

Comment: The CDN was having issues earlier.  It has since been restored.

Comment: If anyone downvotes this question please be so kind as to explain your thinking and add to the knowledge pool.

Comment: is it possible to conditionally execute a script based on whether another script ran?  Seems like we could try to download jquery from more then one CDN that way

Comment: Check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately if you download the files to your own server then you will not experience the same issue again. But there are other considerations:

Plus points for CDNs

1. may be faster network and worldwide mirrors so potentially
   better user experience / performance for your site users;
2. if you link to the latest version, e.g. library-latest-min.js then
   you do not have to alter your source code to get latest bug-fixed version          of library (see negative below).

Negative points

1. If the CDN goes offline your site breaks.
2. If the CDN has a network
   slowdown your users suffer.
3. If you link to the latest version, e.g.
   library-latest-min.js then you do not have to alter your source code
   to get latest big-fixed version of library but if 'latest' holds any
   breaking changes then your site breaks.