# How to Use Multiple CDN for Library Scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

I want to use both "Google Hosted Libraries" and "Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network" for library scripts like jQuery, so that even if one fails to load (e.g. Google), another one is loaded, and the webpage is rendered correctly.

Since Google is banned in China and in some other regions, it is necessary to add backup sources like Microsoft/CDNJS or local files.

Please note that my jQuery is at the bottom of the page, not in the head.

Could you please give me a reliable solution? It'd be great if it's loaded in the following order:
Google>CDNJS/MICROSOFT>Local File

This question is not duplicate! I didn't find any reliable/specific solution for this issue.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295464/5764553) on the question that you're trying not to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following `javascript` right after your initial script tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    (window.jQuery)||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"><\/script>');//]]>
</script>
```

Explanation:

1. Try load the `jQuery` script from a cdn
2. If that fails load a fallback script from js

**Note**: replace the url with your preferred fallback url