# document.write blank page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run this code to get the elements from the paragraph in my HTML code and display:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a p element<br>

This is also a p element.<br>

This is also a p element - Click the button to change the background color of all p elements in this document.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        win = window.open();
        win.document.open();
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            win.document.write(document.getElementById(x.item(i).id).innerHTML);
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how, but I keep getting a blank window. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: `document.write` writes over the page, you don't want to ever be using that as it's bad and outdated

Comment: @SterlingArcher — `document.write` is being called in the new window where there isn't a document. The question says the document is *blank* not that the existing content is overwritten by the new content.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Correctly used, there are many/some possible applications (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014251/402037)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paragraph doesn't have an `id`.

So when you read its `id` property you get `undefined`.

When you call `document.getElementById(undefined)` you get `null`.

When you read `null.innerHTML`, you get an error.

---

You **already** have the element. Don't try to get the ID from the element so that you can get the element.

That is like reading the Dewey Decimal code from a book in your hands so you can go to the shelf it lives on so you can read it.

Also, don't use `item()`, just treat the node list as an array.

```
win.document.write(x[i].innerHTML);
```

Comment: yes perfect it worked ! thank you
but here's my problem is i add an alignment Style it doesn't reflect in the new open window! and that's my main problem
any idea how to fix that ?