# jquery is not loading from the cdn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery in my web page so I have included the script in my HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

If I try to hit the URL: `code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js` it will not load for first few attempts. after that it will load. This is happening from past few days.

These scripts are included at the top of `<head>` and were working good for past and this problem is occurring from couple of days.

Is there something wrong in a way I include these or is there some change that happened in jquery?

**EDIT**:
In developer tools I can see this:
status: (failed) 
Request URL: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js 
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request headers:
Referer: https://somePage.com/ 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36

**If I load the page `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js` in the browser it works for second or the third attempt**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted here.

Comment: Add jquery fallback local file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: When you say _"it will not load"_, what **exactly** is the problem? Is it timing out? Responding with an error status? Check your browser's _Network_ console and post screenshots if there's anything interesting

Comment: In the status it says (failed) and there is no status code .

Comment: maybe you can use developer tool of browser to see whether the request is sent or not, or is there a local cache matched.

Comment: Could you maybe try it in safe mode of firefox. I once had the problem that a plugin blocked the script. If it runs in safe mode that means that some plugin is blocking it.

Comment: The request is sent I did check in developer tools and the status is (failed) and I did a hard reload ctrl+shift+r to make sure it is not from the cache @York Chen

Comment: Its not in safe mode I am using google chrome and its not even in incognito @mrdeadsven

Comment: @SilverSurfer as you have mentioned the answer given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) did help me a lot now I am able to load the jQuery library from other location even if the CDN did not load the file

Comment: @aja Glad to help you =). Remember script tags should be placed at the end of the `body`, before `</body>` for better performance.

Comment: @SilverSurfer cool I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I just put your CDN link both in the `<head>` of a file I'm working on, then tried as well at the bottom of the body and both worked. It's likely that something else in your `<head>` is breaking it.

If you use the same CDN in a basically empty project and just launch a single line of script like alert("it works!") does it pop up for you? If so, your script tag and CDN are not the issue.

Comment: I can see in the developer tools the request is hitting `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js` and the response is not status 200