# How to perform JavaScript ES6 import with fallback to local copy?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

If I have a module "externals.js" that contains:

```
import * as three from "'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/build/three.module.js";
export three;
```

then I can use it without difficulty from "main.js" as so:

```
import three as J3 from "./externals.js";

var renderer = new J3.WebGLRenderer();
// ... do lots of cool stuff with the renderer
```

In particular, by the time execution gets to the call to WebGLRenderer, three.js is all loaded up and I successfully obtain a renderer.

However, if I would like to follow what appears to be a best practice as per [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go) and fall back to a locally cached copy in case cdn.jsdelivr.net is unreachable, the only way I could find to do things in "externals.js" is to use async functions and dynamic import, like so:

```
export var three;
export var threeLoaded = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    var success = false;
    try {
        three = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/build/three.module.js');
        console.log("original import OK");
        success = true;
    } catch(err) {
        try {
            three = await import('./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js');
            success = true;
            console.log("used fallback import");
        } catch(err) {
        }
    }
    if (success) { resolve(); } else { reject(); }
});
```

But now if I leave "main.js" as it is, and if there is any appreciable network delay in obtaining three.js, then J3.WebGLRenderer is undefined at the point that I try to use it and the main application fails. Instead, the only way I could find to proceed in "main.js" in this case is like so:

```
import { threeLoaded, three as J3 } from './externals.js';
main = function() {
    var renderer = new J3.WebGLRenderer();
    // ... do lots of cool stuff with the renderer
}
threeLoaded.then(main);
```

But at least for a simple "main.js," to me this code structure obfuscates the intention that I just want to import some modules and then execute some functions from them, sequentially.

So, the question: is there a way with the ES6 import facility to fall back to a local copy of a module but still have the import operation occur synchronously so that the module is available in the next line of code, as happens with an ordinary single "import" command?

Comment: Since posting this, I found out about the "top-level await" ECMAscript proposal (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) which would solve this issue; I am still curious whether anyone knows of a way to do this without that mechanism.