# Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, cdn

This may be obvious to some, but I've been wondering: why should I depend on [Google's server](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) to host jQuery for my site?

Is it only because it loads faster this way?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi

Comment: No one mentions what Google's policy was on hotlinking to their JS files (given hotlinking is usually frowned upon), so heres the URL where Google mention this is OK and more about the libraries they host: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I link to Google API's cloud for JS libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936399/should-i-link-to-google-apis-cloud-for-js-libraries/)

Comment: Many users already have downloaded jQuery from Google or Microsoft when visiting another site. As a result, it will be loaded from cache when they visit your site, which leads to faster loading time

Comment: You should not use Microsoft or Google. Use MaxCDN. Much more likely to get cache hit, which is the most important thing here
http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/14/jquerys-content-delivery-network-you-got-served/

Answer (score 398, accepted):

This is because:

1. **It increases the parallelism available.**
     (Most browsers will only download 3 or 4 files at a time from any given site.)
2. **It increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit.**
     (As more sites follow this practice, more users already have the file ready.)
3. **It ensures that the payload will be as small as possible.**
     (Google can pre-compress the file in a wide array of formats (like GZIP or DEFLATE). This makes the time-to-download very small, because it is super compressed and it isn't compressed on the fly.)
4. **It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by your server.**
     (Google is basically offering free bandwidth.)
5. **It ensures that the user will get a geographically close response.**
     (Google has servers all over the world, further decreasing the latency.)
6. (Optional) **They will automatically keep your scripts up to date.**
     (If you like to "fly by the seat of your pants," you can always use the *latest* version of any script that they offer.  These could fix security holes, but generally just break your stuff.)

Comment: I love how you keep coming up with more and more reasons. +1 for that alone.

Comment: 6. Googles servers are probably faster than yours!

I'm not sure point 3 is really relevant since anybody can minify just as well as google.

+1 for a great answer :)

Comment: @Paul:  Feel free to add that, but generally it is the client connection that is the bottle neck.  Thanks!

Comment: I feel like #3 probably has more to do with gzip and the like, since jQuery already gives out a minified version.

Comment: And another +1 from me, for listing reasons I would not have thought of. Plus I deleted my own sucky answer (which I thought was somewhat acceptable until Mr. I-Know-Why-To-Use-Google-CDN came along :)

Comment: #6 is not good for the argument and actually negates #2. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12608285/67481) that explains why. The short version is that the cache expiration time is shorter as less-specific versions are referenced.

Comment: #6 is not true anymore: http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/

Comment: So using a CDN for jQuery and other libraries such as font-awesome would be a better option?

Comment: Is this in relation to other CDNs of having a local file? If it's other CDNs, this answer is relevant. But if you are comparing to using local files, well, things might be different.

Comment: Why you shouldn't use it? Because google use it to track you.

Answer (score 60):

There are several scenarios when you might *not* want to use jQuery from Google's CDN:

1. **When you are building an intranet
   application where the web server is
   hosted on the same network as the
   clients.**  If you use Google's CDN
   jQuery, you will be making a call to
   the internet rather than a webserver
   on the local network.  This
   increases bandwidth for your
   organization, and is slower.
2. **When you want to run your application offline**. (Quite linked to the first issue) If you need to work on a development environment (managed for example with [Bower](http://bower.io)), you might need to be able to make your application work without any internet connection (ie: in a train :)
3. **When you need to customize it**. For example if you use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to build the library in order to use only certain modules or setting the [AMD name](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#amd-name)
4. **When you are serving pages over SSL
   that require jQuery.**  You should
   serve the JavaScript over SSL as
   well as your page to avoid security
   problems and warnings.

Also, [Microsoft hosts jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx) on their CDN.  That is another choice comparable to using Google's hosted jQuery.

Comment: Just an FYI that you can use Google's servers to serve up an SSL version of the hosted javascript libraries.  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js works.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Microsoft.  Google gets _way_ too much credit imo.

Comment: Also FYI:  Scheme relative hyperlinks, like  `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/..."`, work.

Comment: And also consider cndjs

Comment: It would be worth adding a point about privacy/tracking here (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311212/does-google-hosted-jquery-helps-google-to-track-visitors)).

Answer (score 29):

This [study](http://flippinawesome.org/2014/03/10/is-jquery-too-big-for-mobile/) by [TJ VanToll](http://tjvantoll.com/) convinced me that it's better to concatenate jQuery with other scripts rather than load it from a CDN.

The reason is the latency involved in fetching jQuery on mobile devices:

> "In 2012 the average RTT time on a mobile network in the United States
>   was 344ms. And that 344ms applies to not only every HTTP request –
>   which the average web page now makes 93 of – but also every DNS lookup
>   and TCP connection... While average RTTs are improving, there are only
>   small additional gains to be had, as current networks are within a
>   small factor of the theoretical limit dictated by physics."

He also cites [this post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/03/18/http-archive-jquery/) from Steve Souders that shows why you're actually **unlikely to get the caching benefit** from using a CDN:

> "Because of the fragmentation in CDN providers, jQuery versions, and
>   protocol usage (http vs. https), the chances of getting a CDN cache
>   hit are shockingly low – and downloading from an external domain has
>   the potential to perform not one, but three round trips (a DNS lookup,
>   a TCP connection, and an HTTP GET)."

Comment: This is not longer true for HTTP2 and SPDY. Today you can host all your external resources in a CDN like Cdnjs.com or something and all files will be download using the same request. Thats basically the same as concatenate.

Answer (score 14):

The greatest benefit is from caching. The theory is that if a visitor visited a site that was loading their JavaScript libraries, say jQuery for example from the Google CDN, then when they visit your website, the library is already in that user’s browser cache and will not have to be downloaded again. This sounds great in theory.

The benefits being shared here and elsewhere are all theoretical. Just came across an in-depth analysis of using a CDN and if it provides the expected performance benefits.
http://www.root777.com/appdev/does-using-google-libraries-api-cdn-give-you-performance-benefits

Comment: This answer is grossly underrated. It provides the equally valid "cons" to the "pro" accepted answer above.

Comment: @user239558 The link wouldn't be dead if the author of the study had actually used a CDN ;-)

The error is: [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/41/d222999437/htdocs/wp-content/themes/prose/functions.php

Comment: The article isn't well thought out. It says that the least common jQuery libs are served by the Google CDN on about 0.5% of all pages. During a general browsing session I visit loads of pages, especially those little links to sites like for example the one that hosts it. Or blog sites. I easily visit 30 unique sites a day, after a week the chances of not having it cached are pretty slim.

Although it may not be cached for all of your user, people who make extensive use of the internet will nearly always have them cached, because they visit far more than 1 unique domain in total.

Answer (score 9):

A major reason NOT to let Google host your jQuery, one that many people don't think about, is that it won't download if you are in China. It's blocked along with many other scripts, fonts etc... hosted by Google CDN's. If you need to reach a Chinese audience you're best to always use a fall back hosted on your own server.
[Google APIS Blocked in China](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkKjn.jpg)

Comment: I disagree @tmthydvnprt. The question is opinionated, so that's where most of the fault lies to begin with, but this does answer the question.

Comment: I came here to same the same thing. If users are in China, most everything from Google is blocked by the great firewall. Though, this is probably a non-issue since lots of people in China use a VPN service, and you probably don't want to target the Chinese market anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers here to "Why you should..." and "Why you should not..."

I simply want to add a list of alternatives to Google if you did want to load jQuery from a CDN.

- CDN JS - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery
- Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0][2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0)
- jsDelivr - https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jquery
- code.jquery.com (StackPath) - https://code.jquery.com/
- Google - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

But to sum it up, you are basically improving your overall website/application performance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update 2021 - Public CDNs no longer increase chance of Cache Hit

When using a [Http Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), the cache key is a combination of the resource itself i.e. `jquery.js` ***as well as*** the Top Level Domain ie. `example.com`.

- **Safari / Webkit implemented in 2013** per [Optionally partition cache to prevent using cache for tracking](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110269)
- **Google implemented in 2020** per [Gaining security and privacy by partitioning the cache](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/http-cache-partitioning/#is_this_standardized_do_other_browsers_behave_differently)
- **Firefox implemented in 2021** per [Enable Top-Level Origin Based HTTP-Cache Splitting](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1594004)

There ar still other benefits of using a CDN, but this long standing performance improvement has been replaced by security concerns.

#### Further Reading

- [Say goodbye to resource-caching across sites and domains](https://www.stefanjudis.com/notes/say-goodbye-to-resource-caching-across-sites-and-domains/)
- [Network partitioning | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/State_Partitioning#network_partitioning)
- [http-cache-partitioning RFC](https://github.com/shivanigithub/http-cache-partitioning#impact-on-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

Usign CDN with a Service Worker, you can download the CDN once in the client lifetime, and not every time you update your code.