# jQuery dialog with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a jQuery dialog on-the-fly.  I'm using this:

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
$(newDiv).html('hello there');
$(newDiv).dialog();
```

I then have this in the html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

When I try running the JS in IE7 I get the following error on the $(newDiv).dialog(); line :
Object doesn't support this property or method.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your code works, you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/W65TL/), that means you probably have a script include problem, make sure that your files are under a `js` folder *beside the page*, or if you intended them to be from site root, use `/js` instead.

Or, [consider using a CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery).

You can make your code a bit more efficient (I realize it's just a test), like this:

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
newDiv.html('hello there');
newDiv.dialog();
```

This works because `newDiv` is *already* a jQuery element, no reason to clone the object each time...or a bit shorter:

```
$('<div />').html('hello there').dialog();
```

Comment: I do already have a js folder under the root which contains jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js.  I also have some other jQuery stuff (Tabs) which are working fine. Doesn't this mean that my jQuery references are ok?
The code gets called via an onclick event for a button.

Comment: I replaced my js references with the following:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
and it all started working.  Do I need some additional .js files in my js folder, even though they're not directly references via a script tag?

Comment: @DEH - Nope that's it if what you're using is all jQuery and jQuery UI, everything is in those 2 files as far as the script goes.  You may also want to include the CSS for jQuery UI the same way.  Take a look at this question for those URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348559/are-there-hosted-jquery-ui-themes-anywhere just replace the `1.7.0` in the URL of whatever theme you want to use with `1.8` (to match your jQuery UI script version), for example: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Just to confirm, my js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js file was a custom js download that did NOT include the jQuery Dialog stuff.  Once I had created a new download containing the Dialog elements then it all worked with my own internal .js references.

Answer (score 23):

Here is an alternative way of creating dialogs and their messages dynamically:

```
     $('<div></div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        open: function() {
          var markup = 'Hello World';
          $(this).html(markup);
        },
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      });  //end confirm dialog
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/DYbwb/

Comment: I have added a line after close function to ensure that the newly created div was deleted when the dialog was closed see http://jsfiddle.net/DYbwb/597/

Comment: Wow, this should have been the user's Accepted answer.  Excellent detail, the jsfiddle was much appreciated.

Comment: KMX - rather than add a button, I took your suggestion and altered the close function (otherwise it only gets deleted when you click the button, not when you use the X to close) - Thanks for the starting point, it is much much easier to tweak someone else's answer than write it from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, what you need is a reference of jquery and jquery ui

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```