# advantages of connecting jquery via online or through inner url

Tags: jquery, api, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery)

I was thinking about... which option is better and specially why. For example I would like to know which advantages there are in speed or performance and their disadvantages. It could also be that their are no disadvantages or advantages. So what would be the difference between these two options:

Connecting jquery via inner url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Connecting jquery via online:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also [3 reasons why you should let Google host jQuery for you](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of using remote (so-called CDN) jQuery is that most users will already have a cached version of the script, so there is no need to load it again.

Comment: So why I call via online is called remote... very good to know. So it gives you less weight for your website and it could be the jquery was already loaded via cache. Just to be sure... cache is a sort of temporal memory while you browse?

Answer (score 0):

The latter has its advantages. Consider that many websites use the Google CDN to host JQuery on their site. It is very likely that when a user enters  your site, the file will already be in browser cache, and thus saves time and bandwidth and also loads your site much faster.

Comment: So the conlusion is that there is an advantage of speed if using what I call "via online". no?

Comment: Both speed and bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am  agreed that they are some real advantages to let Google to store the jQuery library for you but in real life how many companies will let other company like Google to store the files that they are using?

Yes, this is Google after all, but the security is security at the end of the day and I am sure that neither big company will use the Google way.

And you are talking about speed and bandwidth?Well, the jQuery min version is so tiny, and we are even not talking about 1.8.0 new futures that allowed you to generate a js only with the functions you are using.

So, forget this false things about loading js from other sources and try to optimize your projects themselves. I do not know anything about your internet speed or your clients speed but not loading 90 KB can save you nothing, when your application is downloading huge background images and other stuff.

That's my opinion and I am sure a lot will agree with me.