# How to handle events of dynamic created elements without jQuery or zepto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that jquery or zepto `$(selctor).on(event, handler)` will trigger events of dynamic created elements. But I don't use jquery and zepto.I'd like write my code from scratch for both learning and lightweigh.

There are lots of `sth.innerHTML=blabla` and `sth.appendChild(..)` snippets in my codes. I have to bind event to them.

### Update:

I want a simple function like this,

```
function $on(selector, eventType, handler) {
    document.querySelectAll(selector).forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
    });
    // on new DOM insert or replaced, let us call it newDom
      newDom.querySelectAll(selector).forEach(function(el) {
          el.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
      });
}
```

but I don't know if jquery work like this, I want to know it, and complete my function.

Comment: What about event propagation?  This way you don't have to deal with the overhead of binding and unbinding on each element you push in or remove from the dom?

Comment: @Newse, it's unmistakable that jQuery and zepto make some things easier, but it's certainly worthwhile to want to know how to do some things on your own.

Comment: Just for a reference, jQuery has decided to deprecate the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method, if your *dynamic* is creating elements after the event binding.

Comment: @naomik - you are absolutely correct, but what does event propagation have to do with jquery or zepto.  The reason I suggested this technique is because it would mitigate the overhead of adding an event handler to every element that would be added dynamically.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: This guys has written some pure js code that's equal to JQuery  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237233/jquery-functions-equivalent-in-pure-javascript

Comment: @guilin桂林 I've made some edits to my answer below. I hope this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example using the newer [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) recommended by the MDN docs.

This depends on [Element.prototype.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches) which is not widely supported yet. However, I created a little wrapper to make it easier to work with.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/giratapo/1/edit)

```
// live listener function
(function(window) {

  // Element.matches "polyfill"
  (function(e){
    if (typeof e.matches !== "function") {
      e.matches = e.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                  e.mozMatchesSelector    ||
                  e.msMatchesSelector     ||
                  e.oMatchesSelector      ||
                  e.matchesSelector;
    }
  })(Element.prototype);

  function on(selector, eventType, handler) {
    // add listener for all existing elements
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(elem) {
      elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
    });

    // create new "live" observer
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(records) {
      records.forEach(function(record) {
        [].forEach.call(record.addedNodes || [], function(elem) {
          if (elem.matches(selector)) {
            elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
          }
        });
      });
    });

    // watch for DOM changes to body's children and body's subtree
    observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    return observer;
  }

  window.on = on;
})(window);
```

Let's create some elements

```
// sample button generator
function createButton() {
  var b = document.createElement("button");
  b.className = "hello";
  b.innerHTML = "Spaghett";
  document.body.appendChild(b);
}

// create a new button every second
setInterval(createButton, 1000);
```

Actual usage

```
on("button.hello", "click", function(event) {
  alert("spooked ya!");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Notable notes!

I'm using `[].forEach.call(..., fn)` because `querySelectorAll` **does not** return an `Array`. Instead, it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). A NodeList object does not have Array.prototype in its prototype chain and therefore does not have direct access to the .forEach function. [MutationRecord.prototype.addedNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord) also returns a NodeList.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I want