# Downloading the latest 2.x version of jQuery from Google

Tags: jquery, google-cdn

This works:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

But this doesn't:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2/jquery.min.js
```

During development, I like to always be using the latest version of jQuery.

I wonder if there's a way to have it like I used to back when referencing /1/ meant: the latest 1.x version.

Comment: Use the git link for development if you want the absolute latest version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE Otherwise, if you want the latest *stable* version, you'll have to just keep an eye on when a new version is released, there isn't a .latest.js for 2.x

Comment: I understand you're using this for development, but it's still [not a good idea to just reference the latest version automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn/).