# Linking JQuery into my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to include an external jQuery file into my html (first time) but it isn't working, just executing the html without the jquery. (css is working fine)

Here's the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>`
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the jquery code in script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("it works");
});
```

And yes, they are all in the same folder (dropbox folder actually, but I don't think dropbox affects anything)

Comment: Where you read this `script` in source? give only your url in source

Comment: FYI: It's generally accepted to not self-close your `script` tags - do `<script src="..."></script>` instead of `<script src="..." />`. I believe self-closing script tags work everywhere except old IE (IE7 maybe?), but people still generally don't do it.

Comment: If you think about what you have done, you would end up in a Infinite loop because you would put the script in every `src`

Comment: Best you can do is learn to debug this error by referring to developer tools for whatever browser you are using. Quick google will help you to get started with developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

First, remove the extra `src="<script` inside your `<script>` tag.  Also "close" it with a `</script>` tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Second, place the script includes at the *end* of your `<body>` section, just before the `</body>` tag:

```
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

OR, anywhere inside your `<head>` section:

```
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
```

And finally, make sure the URL path is correct for your version:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

It's always smart to link to a full version.  Otherwise, if the code at the URL is updated, your site could suddenly break without warning.

---

If you make the changes as indicated above and add a `<title>` element into your head section...

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    ....
```

... your code will then pass HTML validation.

http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Finally, link to a full version number instead: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Self-close a script? Really? That's completely invalid HTML. Self-closing does not exist in HTML. Most if not all HTML parsers will put everything that follows the script inside of the script itself, as effective you haven't closed it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, my fault for missing his `doctype`... corrected and it now passes [HTML validation](http://validator.w3.org/check) as long as the OP includes a `<title>` element in the `<head>`.

Comment: No problems, +1 now (I would have corrected it myself but I dislike radically changing one else's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Is this a typo? You have an extra `<script` in your src="  "

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" />
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just an fyil if you surround a piece of code with ` (backticks) it will make it a code snippet. So you can have `<script` instead of "(<)script"

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have the full script inside the src, which is wrong.

Comment: The latest jQuery(2.x) is not working on IE8 any more!! Beware!

Comment: [It's always a bad idea to point to the latest jQuery without specifying a full version number. The API may change unexpectedly and your code may fail without explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn/12608285#12608285)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea [jQuery 2.x was never supposed to work on IE8. Only jQuery 1.x supports IE6-8.](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

Comment: @Blazemonger I know, I just wanted to warn you.