# Linking to latest version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, google-cdn

I expect these two links to point to the latest version of jQuery, version 1.11.0.

- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

The code.jquery.com link points to 1.10.2 and the Google one points to 1.9.1.

Can anyone explain why, or indicate something which I might be doing wrong? I have tried clearing my browser cache and even tried the links on other machines.

Comment: jQuery's API has sometimes changed in a way that is not backwards compatible. Connecting to the latest, rather than a specific version could break your pages.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend linking to the latest version of jQuery unless you plan to be consistently checking to make sure that nothing has been deprecated and that your code is up to date.

Comment: I like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn

Comment: Why? Because each site has its own politic regarding which version is the lastest stable one. Or maybe because of some dudes lazyness... ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree with the above comments. Use a specific version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for latest version from google (*although I personally don't recommend you to use latest version*):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Why does it point to 1.9.1?

> The latest version of jQuery may not be compatible with the existing
>   plugins/code on the site. Version updating should be an intentional
>   decision. The latest version has a very short max-age=3600 compares to
>   the specific version of max-age=31536000, which means you won't get
>   the benefits of long-term caching.

[Source](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/faq.md#why-dont-you-automatically-load-the-latest-version-of-jquery-from-the-google-cdn)

So, Google doesn't waste its resources unnecessarily. You'll need to manually upgrade the URL to the latest.

Answer (score 1):

#### Not a good idea to use latest version of jQuery.

But if you really want that specific version, it's at:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This link is the latest **today**, but not in the future.

Comment: He's looking to always have the latest build - again, which isn't a great idea to begin with.