# Starting a New Rails Project with Foundation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, zurb-foundation

When starting a new rails project is better to include a library as a gem or cdn?  I am unfamiliar with the distinct advantages and disadvantages.

The two things I am looking to include are Zurb Foundation & jQuery.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery I'd use a local fallback just in case as well, some people tend to block all google services. Don't ask me why, but there are quite some topics on SO Meta and I've had to deal with that kind of report on my website as well.

Comment: You might look into how the Asset Pipeline works in Rails. One answer is that it depends on how you set up your depolyment or production server.

Answer (score 0):

This [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation) may help you

Personally, I never use CDN.