# Why won't jQuery work in my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a small project for a friend. I recently learned jQuery on Codecademy, and this is my first time incorporating it in to a web page. However, it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Also, if someone could direct me on how to center the text boxes, and so on, to look like the image linked below, please let me know.

[image: screenshot of login form]

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>DNA Translator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> type="text/javascript" src="script.js"</script>
    <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <form>
                DNA: <input type="text" name="dna" placeholder="DNA"><br>
                mRNA: <input type="text" name="mrna" placeholder="mRNA"><br>
                tRNA: <input type="text" name="trna" placeholder="tRNA"<br>
                Amino Acids: <input type="text" name="aminoAcids" placeholder="Amino Acids"<br>
            </form>
            <button id="button" type="button">Tanslate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my stylesheet.css:

```
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#button{
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: inline-block;
    height:25px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#293FE3;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
    /*display: block;*/
    margin: 30px auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
    display:/*block;*/ inline-block;
    height:20px;
    padding:4px 6px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#555;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition:border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition:border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition:border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition:border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s
}
```

Here is the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#button').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#button').fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
    });
});
```

Comment: Because you didn't load it into your page?

Comment: Show your jquery code

Comment: Given your accepted answer, where did you include jQuery?

Comment: It's not included in what is up there. I did edit that, but the ultimate problem was that I was not correctly linking my script.js file. If I could pick to answers I would. They were both needed. but that is the bigger problem I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing your script tag too early

`<script> type="text/javascript" src="script.js"</script>`

Should be

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This was the problem. I knew I was doing something stupid.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include jQuery!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's a library!

Comment: Is it really OK to load the jQuery js file directly from the download link like that? I thought that should only really be used for JsFiddle or JsBin and the like.

Comment: `script` is not a self-closing element, and I suggest removing the `type` attribute. Also consider HTTPS. Apart from that, +1.

Comment: That's a link to the CDN listed on the jquery website. It's not a download link. The other answer is the download link (code.jquery.com)

Comment: So the Content Delivery Network (CDN) is specifically made so you can just load your jquery for your own website from it?

Comment: @Zack ya, that's the purpose of a CDN

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 thanks for the script correction. But why HTTPS? It's not exactly secure information and I would assume some overhead for https. (actually, if the host site is using https, it should be https)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 there's no such thing as a self-closing element in HTML5 anyway. A closing tag for a single element is `[/]?>`. @Zack use a CDN for your common libraries, it'll usually be faster than your site (bonus: it's also cached before the user first loads your site, 9 times out of 10)

Comment: @Zack Yes, that is the purpose of a CDN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery

Comment: @rob you should *always* specify CDN URLs as https, ideally, since it's a remote script that can be man-in-the-middled (if you need plaintext compatibility, use `//domain.tld/resource` instead of `http://` or `https://`)

Comment: @Hiroto It's not just CDN URLs...it's URLs for any resources. And they're called "void elements"

Answer (score 3):

Include the link to the jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure to do this before you call any .js files.

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's a library!

Answer (score 0):

This center alignment of text boxes you can do through css. If you want to use jQuery then download that and include on your page or add directly `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. And then you are ready to use jQuery. What you want to do if you let us know then we can suggest something.

Comment: I know i can do it through CSS, but I'm not nearly as experienced with CSS as you people, and I wanted some input on how to do it.