# Is it better to reference jQuery file include through jQuery CDN?

Tags: jquery, google-cdn

Is it better to reference `jQuery` file inclusion through `jQuery CDN` for better performance?

Like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Or

Is it better to reference stored `jQuery` file in our project?

Like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

As `jQuery CDN` link handles caching, Does it improve performance more than `jQuery` file included from our project?

Comment: Is better using CDN, but always have a fallback to local see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go

Comment: The only drawback is if google servers get unreachable .. As @IrvinDomininakaEdward said, consider using a  fall-back too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First variant. Because google has best world-wide servers.

- Decreased Latency
- Increased parallelism
- Better caching

The best way to initiate jQuery engine:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.10.2");

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
 });
</script>
```

Here is a good article about this:

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: Get `/jsapi/` then.. get `jQuery` ?

Comment: @l2aelba yes. jsapi - Google's universal loader. Take a look [link](https://developers.google.com/loader/)

Answer (score 7):

Do like this with a **fallback**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/libs/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

**CDN first**, if not (or blocked) ? so bring it from your server

[Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery) (For me, my point is about **Cache Hit**)

Comment: but when do u think the file will not be downloaded from CDN?? as far as i think CDNs are much more reliable then personal server.

Comment: No server with 100% uptime. @Dhaval

Comment: @Dhaval, Google's servers can be blocked in Iran or China.

Answer (score 1):

With CDN :

- If the user have already downloaded the file on an other website, the file is already in cache
- If the user haven't the file, the file will always be located on the server nearest to your visitor
- In addition, you will reduce the load on your server, which allows it to render the site faster