# PROs & CONs of jquery-last.min.js over hosted provider or local copy

Tags: jquery

I am searching the web for the **pros & cons** of using the `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` jQuery library **hosted version** or a **copy** of the jQuery library on the local server.

I found some answers on a google search but I want to know that the **stackoverflow** community thinks about this.

Comment: For caching reasons you never want to use any *latest* copy, it's caching will be far shorter/non existent, and you're more likely to end up with a broken website when a breaking update happens to jquery. Instead, always supply a version number when including jquery (or any js/css library for that matter) from a cdn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pro of having the DSN version is that it will get cached when a person check `x` site, so the next time that a person visits another site that used the same DNS version of the script it will be faster to load since it is in the cache of the browser..

Cons is that if the version changes, and some method gets remove, you will have problems ;)

Comment: what do you think when using the current version 1.10.2 of jQuery, what would be the "lifetime" of this version when the user uses the latested versions of firefox, chrome and safari? 6, 12, 24 month? or are the browsers still down-compatible to jQuery versions? (e.g. v2 of jQuery is not supporting IE 6,7,8)

Comment: jquery 1.10.x will likely be maintained for a few more years, until the marketshare for IE6/7/8(combined) drops below a certain level.

Comment: Agree 1.10.x will be the main jquery library for while until IE shares drops, but that will happen faster, since many websites just dont support them anymore

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a local copy, for the simple reason that it makes it possible for me to work without an internet connection.