# Cannot find /jquery-1.7.2.min.js/event/seq/11

Tags: jquery

how do you fix this kind of error

**Cannot find /jquery-1.7.2.min.js/event/seq/11 ?**

I tried looking for answers in the web but no one seems to have this kind of error.

Do I need to use a newer version of jquery? Im afraid that I'd make the problem worse If I use a different one that's why I'm sticking to this old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the path to your file is correct.

However, I'd suggest you to use [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for popular file such as jQuery instead since it has tons of useful features as you can find out more from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably (almost certainly) you're using a plugin that is based on a newer version of jquery..

So, try to download, for example the [2.1.0 version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js).