# jQuery, beginner hello world page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in jQuery. To see my first hello world page, I have below code, but the result is a bare page without any alerting! it seems it can not read from jQuery-1.11.0 which I downloaded in the same directory of my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function() {
      alert ("Hello World");
      });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try making your HTML valid?

Comment: @Kuma yes there is no alert.

Comment: @TimWolla, maybe I should do that first.

Comment: What you tried to achieve ? alert when load the page?

Comment: yes, my main goal is to make sure jQuery can be run in my web framework which is written by dJango.

Comment: Write my answer below to your code and try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML markup is invalid:

1) You need open `<body>` tag

2) You're missing `"` at the beginning of `text/javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ------    ^ missing " here
```

Final code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("document").ready(function() {
                alert("Hello World");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vMG4/3/)**

---

After inspecting your page, the jQuery library that you link to is blank.

```
http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8017/anabaei/exe/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

To avoid this problem, it's better to use a CDN link from jQuery or Google:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem and now it works; But my question is how come is possible because I downloaded and I can see that file in that directory!

Comment: Maybe your file is blank or some problems with your OS :P

Comment: Actually you should put your `<script>` at the end of the page before closing `</body>` tag. It'll boost up your website speed. It's also better to use CDN instead of linking to your own jQuery file. You can find out more informations about the reason why you should do that from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery

Comment: Thanks, it was very productive for me.

Comment: I used to think jQuery script should be written in the header!

Comment: Why do you change the accepted answer? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: No at all it was great, I though I can check as much answer I can :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a starting `<body>` tag.

Your script sources are missing `"`.

Like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Hello World</title>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $("document").ready(function() {
                alert ("Hello World");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try write like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
      <script>
       $(function() {
       alert ("Hello World");
       });
     </script>
   </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

For make more sure your jQuery working fine add this after the alert line in your jQuery

```
$('body').html("<p>Hello World</p>");
```

The text will appear too in your page so your jQuery source was ok.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an opening quote and the opening body tag. Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function() {
      alert ("Hello World");
      });
     </script>
   </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```