# Script tags needed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

What are the script tags I HAVE TO insert into the `<head>` of my HTML???

Here is what I have:

```
<head>
<title>My Web Site</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scrollup.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='verticalsmoothscrolling.js'></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fauna+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

But if I delete first three script tags above and add this one instead:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...everything works the same way (plus it looks clean and neat).

Can anyone explain me in simple words what each of the first three script tags does, and how do they differ from the one I added instead of those three??? Which one would you use?

I prefer the bottom solution but I am not sure if that's correct/best option???

Comment: Are you telling me you use jQuery without having a clue about how even basic JavaScript works...?

Comment: @Kolink -- Scary stuff :)

Comment: I am very new to javascript so I would like to know the difference. As I see no difference here I wanted to know what experience web developer use and if someone would be so kind to simply explain this to me. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_library

Comment: There's no single "right" answer. You should import scripts based on whether you're actually using them. If you're not using a script, you don't need it; if you are, then you do.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see above, I am using scrollup.js and verticalsmoothscrolling.js. But do I need all those scripts above or just the one at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core difference here between the libraries is that one is basic jQuery, while the other two are jQuery UI and its stylesheet. jQuery UI isn't often a library that's included in pages unless it's very deliberate. If you're not sure that you're using it, you're probably not using it.

The tag that you added is simply a newer version of jQuery. The reason everything works the same is that your code likely isn't using jQuery UI, so there's no issue if it goes missing.

Also, you don't HAVE to put your script tags in the `head`. They can go anywhere on the page. However, it's good practice to put your script tags at the BOTTOM of the page. This is so that your page is able to load and render the HTML elements without first having to load JavaScript, which can occasionally cause a bit of hangup on page load.

**Update**

As far as when to use jQuery UI, it's commonly used in projects with very dynamic UI elements. For instance, jQuery UI allows for click/draggable elements, dynamic sorting, resizable elements, etc. You can see a full listing of its features and demos [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

This library stands out because while standard jQuery does support these interactions, it's not quite as easy and clean as using jQuery UI. Note that jQuery UI is an extension of jQuery and relies on jQuery to run.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. So, there is basic JQuery and UI and its stylesheet. How do I know when to use which one?

Comment: I'll update my answer to explain a bit

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I know this is basic but sometimes its not easy to read a ton of stuff online to get simple answer. appreciate your kindness!

Comment: Just read your update. If I understood well I should probably use jquery UI as well because my two .js documents are dynamic (clickable). Is that right? What is the latest script for JQuery UI?

Comment: jQuery supports lots of clickable and dynamic elements. Scripts are rarely dependent on jQuery UI, and if your scripts work without having the jQuery UI scripts tags in your project, you don't need it. If you do decide to use it, you can download it [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: Thank you Brian. You rock! last question: is it better to download jquery or to just to link it like i did above? Or it's the same??? Thank you again!!!

Comment: It's a toss up. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936399/should-i-link-to-google-apis-cloud-for-js-libraries) may help with that decision

Answer (score 0):

You replaced jquery 1.9.1 with jquery 2.0.0. If you want to know, what's different in the new version, you can always take a look at the [patchnotes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not implying on a new version, rather I wanted to understand what's the difference among first three scripts and is it the same if I use the bottom option?

Answer (score 0):

you dont HAVE to put any tags in the head of your page.
Although it is recommended you add META tags, the charset and the TITLE tag to name your page.

javascript can be placed anywhere on a page

Comment: I know about all those things but I wanted to know about those three SCRIPT tags.